# Has the ability to manage password preferences for App Store purchases been removed in iOS 14?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, settings

In iOS 13 and below, it was possible to change settings for App Store purchases by navigating to Settings/Account Name/iTunes & App Store - this can be confirmed by taking a look at the following Apple Support page:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204030

As of iOS 14, however, the "iTunes & App Store" page appears to have been replaced by "Media & Purchases". When tapping on this option, I'm immediately taken to what looks like the profile page for my Apple ID which doesn't give me any password preferences. Has the option to manage these settings now been removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has the ability to manage password preferences for App Store purchases been removed in iOS 14?

No, it is located here:

**Settings > Apple ID > Media & Purchases > Tap 'Account' Icon > Password Settings:**

- Always Require Password
- Require after 15 mins

**NOTE: The 'Account' icon is the little blue circle with a head, located top left.**

This is also where the option to sign out of the App Store is located in iOS 14

[image: iOS 14 App Store Password Preferences]

Comment: I tapped that icon and it only gives an option to "Sign Out of Store" or "Cancel".